# Blueprint/Spring can't find 'classpath:path/to/file.ext' resource having moved project from Talend 6.5.1 to 7.1.1

Tags: spring, talend, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi

In a Talend ESB (SE) project, I have a bean instantiated in the "Spring" configuration using a route resource.

In version 6.5.1 the following (used as a parameter) works fine.

```
<bean class="java.lang.String">
   <constructor-arg>
     <bean class="org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils" factory-method="copyToByteArray" >
        <constructor-arg value="classpath:query/sqlQuery.sql" type="java.io.InputStream" />
     </bean>
   </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

but this doesn't for in my Talend 7.1.1 project. It seems to be unable to find the resource. I've looked in the created `.kar` file, and the resource is in the project `.jar` in the `query` folder.

[EDIT] It appears that Talend 7.1.1 encloses the "Spring" configuration in a `<blueprint>` element, which perhaps has change the way in which this functions.

I presume that something has changed in the way Talend packages the route, or in the way that the Spring xml is interpreted. Camel has no problem finding resources, for example `from("sql:classpath:query/sqlQuery.sql")`, but the "Spring" classpath search seems not to be able to find them.

I've tried substituting `classpath*:` for the straight classpath in the parameter as that had been suggested in some of the answers I'd seen to "resource not found" questions, but this didn't seem to be valid and was interpreted as a straight filename.

Am I doing something wrong with the classpath declaration? Is there another way of setting a spring/blueprint bean property with the contents of a resource file?

I've also tried explicitly declaring a ClassPathResource bean and it claims the resource does not exist when using the `getInputStream()` method, despite the fact I can see it if I open up the contained jar file.

Has the wrapping of the created feature in Maven terms (from Talend 7) had some impact on the classpath I need to use?

Comment: Having looked further, it seems that if I use the object's ClassLoader I can find the resource, but if I use Spring I can't. Has something broken the resource loader process for Spring?